# Is there a website that shows the popularity of CI/CD tools?

Tags: continuous-delivery

There are websites that indicate the popularity of [programming languages](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) and [open source tools](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/07/tracking-the-explosive-growth-of-open-source-software/). Is there something comparable for CI/CD tools as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I normally use [stackshare](https://stackshare.io/). It doesn't show you usage as reported by the people running the tools but it has a decent community size and seems to be gaining more use rather than less.

It lets you compare tool features, community popularity and shows you who else is using those tools in their stack if that matters to you.

Comment: [Do you know how to add a new tool to stackshare?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110036/128573)

Comment: It's been a while since I've used it to add a new tool but I'm pretty certain you need to register and share your stack, that way they get more tools.

As far as Spinnaker goes, Netflix haven't added it to their stack so I imagine noone has added it yet.

Comment: Does netflix need to add it or is everybody allowed to do that?

Comment: everyone can IIRC

Answer (score 6):

Although not entirely relevant to your question in terms of popularity, [devops bookmark](http://www.devopsbookmarks.com/) is a very nice website which helps discover tools and frameworks in the DevOps landscape.

You are also able to filter tools and frameworks which works with different languages, platforms, licenses and topics which is really handy!

Answer (score 5):

I really like the [Cloud Native Landscape](https://github.com/cncf/landscape). The tools are categorized in a huge map.

Also you can visit [awesome-ciancd](https://github.com/ciandcd/awesome-ciandcd) for a bunch of tools and a brief explanation about each of them.